# GitHub pages custom domain I did all as asked :(

Tags: github, github-pages

I did all what github pages asked me, but I cant get it working.
if you go to [thuis kweken](http://thuis-kweken.nl)

I set it on my side a records to point to:
[image]

and my github page redirects to: davorradic.github.io 
GitHub says in the settings that it doesn't work take a look at picture:
[image]

so any help would be great, thank you

Comment: I don't see where's the problem. It is working. It is showing exactly the `h1` you have in your HTML file and it redirects to your custom domain.

Comment: Don't forget - nameserver changes can take up to an hour to propagate!

Comment: yes now it works, so the problem was, just wait :)